# Running an accuracy formula

Tags: python

I am extremely new to python and i wanted to run an accuracy formula. The formula is like this X - Y(whichever of the two is bigger)/ The biggest number(either X or Y). My Y is this `Y = [46.65347546, 49.52538101, 50.71174784, 47.95042085, 53.36249628, 48.50331361, 49.20114466, 55.90266617]` and my X is this `X = [60,51,54,61,51,50,55,59]`. I want to run this formula for each individual value and then the average of all the values. How can i write this formula in python? What i'm not sure how to do is how to subtract and divide with the biggest number of the two.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Yes sorry about that, edited my post

Comment: You need a `for` loop and you need `abs()` and `max()`. All three are basic Python tools, and there are numerous tutorials on how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use `zip` and then compute the accuracy

```
accuracy = map(lambda t: abs(t[0] - t[1])/max(t[0], t[1]), zip(X, Y))
```

This returns the expected result (python3)

```
>>> print(*accuracy)
[0.22244207566666663, 0.02891409784313732, 0.0608935585185185, 0.21392752704918033, 0.04427259676165963, 0.029933727800000014, 0.10543373345454551, 0.052497183559321974]
```